# CakePHP Array Checkbox, Black hole error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP i tried to submit a form, which has an array input field.

Below is the code i used.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('statusid.', array('value'=>$o['Order']['id'])); ?>
```

When i tried to submit the form i got a blackhole security error.

How can i fix it ?

I noticed that when i submitted the code below it works.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('statusid', array('value'=>$o['Order']['id']));?>
```

Is there a way to make an array checkbox in CakePHP please guide me.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FormHelper and make a checkbox array named statusid this way.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('statusid.0', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'value' => $o['Order']['id']));
echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with blackhole appears when 'hiddenField' is set to false. Although it's set to true by default, it's possible that OP has it defined somewhere globally for entire Form object.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('statusid.', array(
'value' => $o['Order']['id'], 
'hiddenField' => true)); ?>
```